# How can I send an image from my NextJs13 application to my client

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Next.Js13 and React with Javascript to try and make an account system.
When a user logs in Im using the credentials settings from Next-Auth with

```
await signIn("credentials", { email: email, password: password})
```

In my database I also have a profile picture that I want to display which is stored in base64 format that I want to display in my nav bar on client side.
Im struggling to understand whats the best way to send this data back to the client to display.
Currently I have this code in my navbar

```
async function ProfileOrSignIn() {
    const { decodedImage, setDecodedImage } = useContext(DecodedImageContext); // eventually I wanted to use this store the decoded image in react context
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const [retrievedImage, setRetrievedImage] = useState(false)

    if (session && session.user) {
        if(!retrievedImage) {
            setRetrievedImage(true)
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/account", {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })
            const user = await res.json()
            const byteArray = response.split(',').map(user.image.data.data);
            const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray);
            const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Array));
            const ProfilePicture = ({ data }) => <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${data}`} />

            return (
                <div className="flex gap-4 ml-auto text-green-700">
                    <ProfilePicture data={base64String} />
                    <ProfileDropDown username={session.user.email}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={() => signIn()} className="text-green-600 ml-auto">
            Sign In
        </button>
    )
}
```

Which should retrieve the data on user sign in and display the image but I'm finding that decode isnt working but also the function enters many times.
Is there a better way to retrieve the user data and display the image?

---

---